# Spring security 4.2.3, OAUTH 2, /oauth/token endpoint, CORS not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

Angular 5 app needs to login a user. Token request is sent to /oauth/token. The preflight OPTIONS request(sent by Chrome) fails because of CORS.

I tried to follow the examples at [Spring Security 4.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#cors) and various questions and responses on Stackoverflow.

Here is my code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/fapi/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .realmName("MY_REALM");
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    ............
}
```

And here is the request from Chrome

```
General Headers

Request URL: http://api.example.com/oauth/token
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: 127.65.43.21:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade


Request headers

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: api.example.com
Origin: http://example.com
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
```

Response:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1111
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 03:23:15 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MY_REALM"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

And the error in console:

```
Failed to load http://api.example.com/oauth/token: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Comment: check out my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55463965/1848555

Answer (score 1):

I could not make it work with the CorsFilter provided by Spring.

The work around here helped.

[Spring security, cors error when enable Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625488/spring-security-cors-error-when-enable-oauth2)

The part of final code

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@WebFilter("/*")
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("doFilter");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, origin, x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }    
}
```

In the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
      //.cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/fapi/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .realmName("MY_REALM");
    }

    /*
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }*/
    ............
}
```

I am still waiting for an example that makes it work with Spring Security's CorsFilter.

Comment: `/oauth/token` is secured using basic authentication. And the client id and secrets are used for that. Why did you removed that authentication? That breaks the security which OAuth2 provide.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of what you have done, write a custom cors filter like the following

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN);

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }
    }
```

And modify your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` override to

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/fapi/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .realmName("MY_REALM");
    }
```

Comment: Dint work. This one did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625488/spring-security-cors-error-when-enable-oauth2?rq=1